# How to do multiple COUNT in one MySQL request?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with MySQL.

I have these requests :

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM users_vuln 
WHERE vuln_id IN (48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62) 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

and

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM users_vuln 
WHERE vuln_id IN (48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62) 
AND concerned = 1 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

That works well alone, but I want to regroup these 2 requests in only 1 by having 2 columns for each `COUNT`.

like this :

| user_id | COUNT1 | COUNT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 | 2 |

because for now, i only have this :

| user_id | COUNT1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 9 |

and

| user_id | COUNT2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

THANKS FOR YOU FUTURE ANSWERS ! <3

Comment: `COUNT(*) WHERE {condition}` is equal to `SUM({condition})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT1,
    SUM(concerned = 1) AS COUNT2
FROM users_vuln
WHERE vuln_id IN (48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62)
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: `COALESCE(SUM(concerned = 1), 0)` maybe..